# Join one Table to the Same Table for MULTIPLE Times in Lambda

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, join, lambda, inner-join

I have a Student entity and a City entity in my MVC4 application and there are 3 City codes in Student table like that:

**Student Entity:**

```
StudentID | StudentName   | BirthCity | LivingCity | UniversityCity |
1           Christof        01           02            03
...
```

**City Entity:**

```
CityID | CityName | 
01       NewYork
02       Los Angeles
03       Washington
...
```

I want to join Student entity to City entity and show 3 different City names according to their values as indicated above. I have tried with some examples, but they are related to joining different tables (I need to aggregate the same table 3 times : City). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea to use join. See below:

**Model:**

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        StudentID = 0;
        StudentName = string.Empty;
        BirthCity = string.Empty;
        LivingCity = string.Empty;
        UniversityCity = string.Empty;
    }

    public Student(int id ,string name, string bName,string lName,string uName)
    {
        StudentID = id;
        StudentName = name;
        BirthCity = bName;
        LivingCity = lName;
        UniversityCity = uName;           
    }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string BirthCity { get; set; }
    public string LivingCity { get; set; }
    public string UniversityCity { get; set; }
}
```

**query:**

```
 Students.Select (
              s => new  Student()
                 {
                    StudentID = s.StudentID, 
                    StudentName = s.StudentName, 
                    BirthCity = Cities
                       .Where (c => (c.CityID == s.BirthCity))
                       .Select (c => c.CityName)
                       .SingleOrDefault (), 
                    LivingCity = Cities
                       .Where (c => (c.CityID == s.LivingCity))
                       .Select (c => c.CityName)
                       .SingleOrDefault (), 
                    UniversityCity = Cities
                       .Where (c => (c.CityID == s.UniversityCity))
                       .Select (c => c.CityName)
                       .SingleOrDefault ()
                 }
           )
```

Comment: I got error. I think "StudentID" and "StudentName" would be CityID and CityName. But when I use like that I get an error like "AnonymousType#1 does not contain a definition for 'CityID' and no extension method 'CityID' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?".

Comment: You got AnonymousType error because I didn't define the selection type . Because you need to define a new model for the returning the list. Let me update, it'll be clearer.

Comment: Sorry, but it dis not make any sense. On the other hand, I could managed to use the similar code with lambda Join with 2 table (without needing to use Viewmodel). So, is it possible to revise your code so that to be used in the same manner? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help. I tried not using viewModel. I updated it again, hope it'll give you another idea.

Comment: Thanks for your kind helps. It was useful, but I think there is no need to make any modification on Model or Entity side. We just need to revise lambda expression. Nevertheless thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with subqueries. It could also be done with joins.

```
SELECT StudentId,
    (SELECT CityName FROM City WHERE CityId = s.BirthCity),
    (SELECT CityName FROM City WHERE CityId = s.LivingCity),
    (SELECT CityName FROM City WHERE CityId = s.UniversityCity)
FROM Student s
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need a LAMBDA Expression sample instead of SQL.